# jQuery: how to add array of objects in an existing <li>?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an array of objects and I want to add these to the existing li. I want to add certain properties of the array objects to the li. I found some answers on StackOverflow like,

```
$("#header ul").append('<li><a href="/user/messages"><span class="tab">Message    Center</span></a></li>');
```

this talks about adding a single element but I have an array of objects and I want to add certain properties like display, and other properties to the li.

Comment: `$(object).each(function(key,value){ ....//append code ....});` it depends on how's your object is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop through the Array and append each item as a list item to the UL

```
var Arr= [ "your","Array" ];
$.each(Arr,function (key,val) {
 $("#header").append("<li>"+val+"</li>");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this following snippet as an example to append `<li>` element  to another html element.

```
var html = "";
$.each(array_list, function(key, value){
    html = html + "<li id="+value+"><span>You element here</span></li>";
})

$('#header').append(html);
```